# What is the age of The Witch of the Waste in Howl's Moving Castle?

Tags: howls-moving-castle

What is the age of The Witch of the Waste in *Howl's Moving Castle*?

I need to know for a project of mine.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if [the wiki](https://howlscastle.fandom.com/wiki/Witch_of_the_Waste) would help, it already has good information. Regarding your question, strictly based on the web info, 273 years old.

Comment: I'd be really skeptical about that info. According to that article's [history](http://howlscastle.wikia.com/wiki/Witch_of_the_Waste?action=history), it started with ["Middle-aged"](http://howlscastle.wikia.com/wiki/Witch_of_the_Waste?diff=3888&oldid=3847) to ["Ancient"](http://howlscastle.wikia.com/wiki/Witch_of_the_Waste?diff=4202&oldid=4155) to ["273"](http://howlscastle.wikia.com/wiki/Witch_of_the_Waste?diff=4401&oldid=4400) without any references. Cross-checking whether she is 273 years old (including in Japanese) also doesn't give any result.